# Installing Percona Server error: keyserver

Tags: mysql

I am having an error trying to install Percona Server via APT.

First they say you have to add their key, and this is where I get stuck.

I am issuing this command and get errors, anyone can help?

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 1C4CBDCDCD2EFD2A                                                                                                                          ~
gpg: requesting key CD2EFD2A from hkp server keys.gnupg.net
gpgkeys: key 1C4CBDCDCD2EFD2A not found on keyserver
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

Comment: Still not working (28/3/2011 1:00am gmt+0)

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: It's right there: **gpgkeys: key 1C4CBDCDCD2EFD2A not found on keyserver**

Comment: Still not working (1/4/2011 3:00pm gmt+0) –

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I encountered the same problem, then found this page through Google. Fortunately we still had the key available locally on another server. Save the following to a text file `percona.key` and import it with `cat percona.key | sudo apt-key add -`.

[ KEY REMOVED ] See https://www.percona.com/downloads/RPM-GPG-KEY-percona for the current key.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Great solution. Eventually, the uri worked, but this is definitely a great one when that uri is not available

Comment: Everyone should probably ignore the public key provided here on an editable answer via HTTP, and instead obtain the public key from a secured & trusted source.

Answer (score 4):

The key is also directly available from the Percona website.
Import it as following:

```
wget -O - http://www.percona.com/redir/downloads/RPM-GPG-KEY-percona | gpg --import
gpg --armor --export 1C4CBDCDCD2EFD2A | apt-key add -
```

---

Edit: Percona is going to change their SSH key before the end of this year.
See instructions on their website http://www.percona.com/ssh-key-rotation/instructions

Comment: This question is about the GPG keys used for signing the packages in the percona repository, not the SSH keys of their servers!

Comment: Yes. The top part addresses that question, see the key id. The link to ssh-key rotation is not directly related but people searching for percona key errors might stumble on it.